# Expo (SDK49) - React Native Reanimated Animation Issue (not working) After EAS Build (apk)

Tags: react-native, expo, bottom-sheet, react-native-reanimated, expo-router

I'm encountering an issue with my Expo (SDK49) app where the animations, implemented using the React Native Reanimated library, work flawlessly in development mode (Expo Go) on both the emulator and my physical device. However, after building the app using EAS Build, the animations cease to function. Moreover, attempting to open my BottomSheet (utilizing the gorhom bottom sheet), which relies on React Native Reanimated, leads to a sudden app crash without any apparent error message.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you could provide to help resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Dependencies:

expo": "~49.0.18"

expo-router": "^2.0.0",

react-native": "0.72.6",

react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",

react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",